# Flashing galaxy s5 issues

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, odin

I am having issues flashing my Samsung Galaxy S5 with a new firmware.

Whenever I use odin to flash the new firmware it would say `Failed (size)`

This lead me to issues with the PIT file, alas flashing that by its self did little other than make the phone stay on the splash screen.

Following more information I was told the issue could be with hidden.img.ext4 which I should flash separately as a .tar file.

However if I flash the tar.md5 and then flash the 'hidden' the tar.md5 still fails and the flashing of hidden puts me back to the continuous splash screen.

Any idea what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me was to flash it, let it fail, extract the rom file (tar.md5) flash the system.img and then the hidden.img after the first. Reboot in safe mode (volume up + home button + power) and boot from /system